# consuming magento REST api from c#

Tags: c#, api, magento, rest

This is sunil very much new to use MAGENTO rest api. I have to make an application to use magento rest api for retrieving inventory, order details, creating products, updating stocks. But i am little confusing about how to consume magento api using c# from retrieving authentication token to retrieving all details of our store. Kindly give some suggestion or some sample c# code.

Below i am giving my code what i tried till now. But error gives me "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

var consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

```
        var uri = new Uri("http://enterprise-admin.user.magentotrial.com/oauth/initiate");

        // Generate a signature 
        OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();
        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string parameters;
        string normalizedUrl;
        string signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret,
        String.Empty, String.Empty, "POST", timeStamp, nonce, OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1,
        out normalizedUrl, out parameters);
        //signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature);
        signature = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(signature);

        StringBuilder requestUri = new StringBuilder(uri.ToString());
        requestUri.AppendFormat("?oauth_consumer_key={0}&", consumerKey);
        requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce={0}&", nonce);
        requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0}&", timeStamp);
        requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0}&", "HMAC-SHA1");
        requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_version={0}&", "1.0");
        requestUri.AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0}", signature);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(requestUri.ToString()));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: are you made? you gonna integrate magento code (PHP) with C#!
let us know what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am just doing r&d about how to do. After lots of search i got php codes from magento sites. i created a free demo account on magento enterprise edition. got consumer key and consumer secret key. Here i stucked since 2 days. unable to code in c# for consuming magento rest api service.

Comment: you can use soap as well as rest magento api.
More about magento api you can find in below link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

@ViralShah api mean to access across different platforms either its php, #c or java. no matters.

Comment: I have to do rest api not soap. But for magento rest api i am getting error when i am trying now. In question i am giving my code what i tried.

Comment: You are adding the authentication parameters to the url and instead they need to be in an Authorization header.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html

Answer (score 1):

I recently started a project for a C# REST API client for Magento that might help you out:

https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi

It's not yet feature complete, but the oauth authentication is implemented. The code uses restsharp which has support for oauth authentication.
Explanation of the authentication steps is at https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi/wiki/Authentication-steps